# UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView

Tags: android, android-fragments

I looked at existing posts with the same error but code/implementation is different to mine, however the suggestions in some of the posts has not helped to resolve the issue. I am trying to replace a fragment which displays grid (list of images) with another fragment upon an image click. I see the error "Java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView" during runtime but couldn't make out which part of the code is resulting in this error and what needs to be done to fix this issue. Appreciate your help to resolve this. Code is as below:

Fragment with grid (list of images):

```
public class OneFragment extends Fragment {

public OneFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

private ListView mListView;
GridView grid;
String[] web = {"Doctors","Dentists","Test" };
int[] imageId = {R.mipmap.doctors,R.mipmap.dentists,R.mipmap.ic_launcher};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
    int   iconSize=getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(android.R.dimen.app_icon_size);

    CustomGrid adapter = new CustomGrid(view.getContext(), iconSize);
    GridView gridview = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.grid);
    gridview.setAdapter(adapter);

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "You Clicked at " +web[+ position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("MyApp", "I am here");

            //setContentView(R.layout.list_item_main);

            ListItemMainFragment nextFrag = new ListItemMainFragment();

            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            ft.replace(R.id.grid, nextFrag);
            ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_NONE);// it will anim while calling fragment.
            ft.addToBackStack(null); // it will manage back stack of fragments.
            ft.commit();
        }
    });

    return view;
 }
}
```

Fragment Resource file:

```
<GridView
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:columnWidth="100dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/grid"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Fragment for Replacement:

```
 public class ListItemMainFragment extends Fragment implements  Item.DataListener {
private ListView mListView;

public ListItemMainFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_main, container, false);
    mListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_list_view);

    //final String DBReference = "all/" + position + "/" + web[+position];
    final String DBReference = "all/0/Doctors";
    Item.getRecipesFromDB(ListItemMainFragment.this, DBReference);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void newDataReceived(ArrayList<Item> itemList) {
    ItemAdapter adapter = new ItemAdapter(mListView.getContext(), itemList);
    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
 }
}
```

Item List Resource file:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/item_list_view"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
</ListView>
```

Comment: Looks like it's the `FragmentTransaction` in the `GridView`'s `OnItemClickListener`. You're trying to transact a `Fragment` into the `GridView`. - `ft.replace(R.id.grid, nextFrag);`

Comment: I used the code as `(ViewGroup) getView().getParent()).getId()` to retrieve the id of Fragment container. Is that right?

Comment: You could just use the `R.id` that you passed in the `FragmentTransaction` that loaded `OneFragment` initially. Also, I would mention that it might be better to have the `Activity` handle the transaction, instead of the current `Fragment` itself.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please elaborate on why it is better to have the Activity handle the transaction? Also can you point me to an example or code sample on how this transaction handled as an activity.

Comment: Well, it's not strictly necessary, but from an OOP perspective, the less a given class knows about other classes, the better. If you want to have the `Activity` handle it, you'd create an `interface` that the `Activity` implements, and with that you can then signal the `Activity` to perform the transaction, though the actual `FragmentTransaction` code would be pretty much the same, wherever you put it. There's an example of using such an `interface` on [this developer page](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html#DefineInterface).

Comment: Thank you. R.id has resolved the issue. I will explore the link provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this inside your `Fragment Resource file` where your grid view is, add an id called `content`(or any other name) to your Relative layout like this`android:id="@+id/content"`  then in the code where your are doing your fragment replacement, edit this line of code `ft.replace(R.id.grid, nextFrag);` to be `ft.replace(R.id.content, nextFrag);`. I was in the same dilemma, this worked for me.

```
<RelativeLayout>
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/content"

<GridView
   android:numColumns="auto_fit"
   android:gravity="center"
   android:columnWidth="100dp"
   android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:id="@+id/grid" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Java code `class OneFragment`

```
        ListItemMainFragment nextFrag = new ListItemMainFragment();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        ft.replace(R.id.content, nextFrag);
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_NONE);// it will anim while calling fragment.
        ft.addToBackStack(null); // it will manage back stack of fragments.
        ft.commit();
```

Comment: Thank you. The code sample helped resolve the issue.

Comment: @dacscan3669 Please acknowledge or mark my answer as correct. Good to know you were sorted out

Comment: @dacscan3669 Are you now able to display the next fragment when you click an image on your gridview?